# Add space after 8 characters then add space after every 4 characters

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing, sed

Here is the sample input:

```
 AbbigailAbieAbbyAbbi
```

Using sed, I have separated them into 4 characters but seems like I got a problem because I have to separate the first 8 characters first then add spaces after every 4 characters

```
sed 's/.\{4\}/& /g
```

That is the code I used for sed. Any help?
The output should be

```
Abbigail Abie Abby Abbi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
$ echo  AbbigailAbieAbbyAbbi | sed -e 's/.\{4\}/& /2g' 
Abbigail Abie Abby Abbi
```

Answer (score 3):

With posix `sed`:

```
$ echo AbbigailAbieAbbyAbbi | sed 's/.\{4\}/& /g; s/ //'
Abbigail Abie Abby Abbi
```